# How to wrap symbols in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I see and try this code that wraps only letter in a span and works but I want also to include the symbols in a span, can anyone help me? I really don't know how to add a symbol!

```js
$('.ml2').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});
```

```css
.letter{
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="ml2">Welcome to my Website!</div>
```

I did get the `Welcome to my Website` string but it does't include the exclamation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of alternating with just `\w`, alternate with a *character set* that includes `\w`, and you can add whatever symbols you want to permit into the character set:

```js
$('.ml2').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|[\w!])/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
  //                                                 ^^^^^
});
```

```css
.letter {
  border:1px solid green;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ml2">Welcome to my Website!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to wrap everything that is not a space?

```js
$('.ml2').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/[^ ]/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});
```

```css
.letter{
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="ml2">Welcome to my Website!</div>
```